# WordPress upload folder stuck in 2017

Tags: uploads

Whenever I upload items to WordPress via the Media Library it is saved in `wp-contents/uploads/2017/12`.

I tried disabling the year based upload setting and reenabling it but this didn't work. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Are you sure that the server's time is correctly configured?

Comment: Yes it’s correct, additionally I just learned that it only happens for PDFs of that helps